# Nav Menu not Responsive when using Twitter Bootstrap in Drupal

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-7, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am currently working on a website project based on Drupal 7 where initially the static html templates were made using Bootstrap.

I have now converted these into page templates on Drupal; in the static templates, the responsive navigation works, but after having plugged them into Drupal, they no longer work.

I have told the .info file to point to the appropriate js and css files, but can't figure out why, as soon as I moved the site across to the CMS, this function stopped working.

The project is [here](http://denvirdev.info).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of thoughts:

1) Are you using Drupal's bootstrap base theme? https://drupal.org/project/bootstrap that might be helpful as you work on this.

2) Have you installed the jquery_update module? https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update  The version of jquery that ships with Drupal older then the 1.7 required for bootstrap.

Good Luck!

Comment: Your second point worked a treat. Thank you kindly! And I will most definitely make a note of this Bootstrap theme you mention, as I was unaware.

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at your code, you didn't add required Bootstrap markup that triggers the display of the `navigation bar toggle` and the `navigation links default view` between different screen sizes.

Your code must be adjusted to be something like:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <?php
          print theme('links__system_main_menu', array(
              'links'       => $main_menu,
              'heading'     => null,
              'attributes'  => array(
                  'class'   => array('nav navbar-nav'),
              ),
          ));
          ?>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually helped a great deal. I marked the answer by Sean Reiser as correct, as it helped the menu appear. This actually helped with the formatting/layout of all the menu elements once I updated the jquery. Much appreciated!